# I don't know how should I set my mac for "Installing Hyperledger Composer Playground locally"!

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I don't know how should I set my mac for Installing Hyperledger Composer Playground locally . what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Install the pre-reqs
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs

then install the development environment
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools